# UINavigationController in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios8

In my sample code I use a `UINavigationController`. I have a `UIViewController` for saving new data into Core Data, then I want to close this `UIViewController` and return to previous:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender : AnyObject) {

    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let projectEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    var newPerson = AddrBook(entity: projectEntity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    newPerson.lastname = lastNameField.text
    newPerson.firstname = firstNameField.text
    context.save(nil)
    self.navigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

But `self.navigationController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` isn't working.... What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! I solved problem:

```
self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```